# Build - Make module/project uses wrong build type

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.2

As long as I used android studio 3.1 everything was working fine. But after the recent update to 3.2 I see following behaviour:

- calling "build"/"make module" leads to execution of `Executing tasks: [assemble]`
- calling "build"/"make project" leads to the same, assemble task is executed as well

Before the update I was able to exectue the correct assemble task (like `assembleDebug<...>`).

Does anyone know where I can correct this? Can I somehow check which task is bound to those menus and edit them? I have this problem with one project only...

Currently I have to manually execute the gradle task to get what I want, menu entries seem to be broken...

**Setup**

- I am using flavours
- I have selected a build variant of debug type, all my modules are set to debug as well:

  - apps build variant: `devWithoutTestWithAccessibilityDebug`
  - all other modules build variant: `debug`

**Current solution**

I use my own gradle tasks for my most common development build like following for now:

```
task runDev (type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDevWithoutTestWithAccessibilityDebug') {
    commandLine android.getAdbExe().toString(), "shell",
        "monkey",
        "-p", "com.my.app.debug",
        "-c", "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", "1"
}
```

**What I tried**

Clean project like following:

- delete ALL *.iml files
- delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folder
- delete all temp files
- import project again
- sync project with gradle files
- create app run configuration again and start it

Still I end with the same result...

Comment: I would suggest checking the `idea.log` file of Android Studio. This doesn't seem to be a project or Gradle problem due to the fact that you can run gradle tasks from the command line. Also could suggest removing the project from Android Studio, cleaning the project from IDE related files (`.idea`, `.iml`) and `build` folders, then importing the Gradle Project back again. Do be careful with the cleaning though and always have a backup of the project.

Comment: added a "what I tried" paragraph to my question... Cleaning does not help, did try this already... When I check the log there is nothing I can find that could be related to this issue imho, but I've no idea what I should look for. After repeating the clean again and building the project there are only a few warning lines and a lot of info lines in the log but no errors... And nothing related to the build type...

Comment: Could you check the module `iml` file and search for `ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME`? What `value` do you get? If you could provide us with that file also that would be good..